# Fresh migration, functioning locally, backend issues (Template Manager, Matrix)

Tags: matrix, admin

I'm running out of ideas on how to debug this, hoping someone has some knowledge to share.

I've been working on a site locally with EE, Exp-resso Store and Matrix/Matrix Multi-Upload. All plugins are current, as is the EE install (currently 2.7.3).

I'm rebuilding a site, and I planned to move the new site to a subdirectory of the old site for remote access, testing, QA, etc. There were issues with the old site's back-end (among many other things). Details below.

While working local, I've run into no issues. However, today after moving the site successfully to the server, I'm seeing issues in the back-end. These seem to specifically relate to the Matrix plugin (it may not be Matrix's fault, but it's being affected) and the Template Manager. All of these issues were present on the old site. Apart from sharing a server and a database, the two builds are separate. Separate database entries, CSS files, JS, etc.

Dreamhost is the server. PHP 5.4. Possible FastCGI issue? I'm out of ideas.

Console is giving me this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'ee_focus'
```

[image]

Comment: what do you have in browser debugging console? Needs to understand where exactly this issue coming from. Right now we just see that some js error have place. Why this happend? Some files can miss or some files can load completely (usualy is files in  EE combo_load ). Do u use apache/nginx?

Comment: I see: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'ee_focus'. Added to OP.

Comment: ee_focus is load as part of combo_load. Open Network panel in Chrome inspector or just html source of you publish page and find script with "ee_focus" or just check all links "M=combo_load" - just open this links and look if they load completely and don't have any errors.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't seem to find ee_focus anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess your files didn't upload correctly to the server. Reupload all your EE files to the server... specifically, make sure your /themes directory in 100% uploaded.

Also, make sure you are changing/setting directory & file permissions on the server.